# apache rewrite with some complex query string

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I want rewrite something from

```
www.domain.com/index.php?search=product/model&model_name={query string}
```

to

```
www.domain.com/{query string}.html
```

Here is my rewrite code, but not work, need for a help, thanks.

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?search=product/model&model_name=(.*)$ index.php/$1.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`, you need to use a `RewriteCond` and match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` var:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=product/model&model_name=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ index.php/%1.html [L]
```

This makes it so when someone requests `www.domain.com/index.php?search=product/model&model_name={query string}`, they get served the content at `/index.php/{query string}.html` while their browser's URL in the address bar is unchanged (still the URL with the query string).